# Filters With Image on Collection page in magento

Tags: magento

[here is my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC4t9.png)

this is my filter showing on collection page now i want this filter with image like this 
[here is my example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBdDa.png)

Comment: please explain the problem briefly, share the piece of code etc.

Comment: it's not code i just create attribute with name 14-k metal in magento and i set Use In Layered Navigation with filterable now it showing on collection page which is good now i want my filter with image like i want  14 metal filter come with image like i paste second image in my question it psd it's not my magento page

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

As you want to show attribute image in layered navigation. this is not possible by default in magento. You can achieve this using below solutions:

Soution 1: Modify the `catalog\layer\filter.phtml` Template file in your current theme to apply condition for particular attribute using function `$this->getName()` and add images instead of label for the options.

Solution 2: Purchase advance layer navigation extension.